# draw a circle when certain condition is met

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt, frame

My program is to convert the letters to some signals.My main method generates some random letters. The letter  is passed to another method which calls repaint() method based on the Letter generated.The PaintComponent() method is used to drew a circle filled with white color.When i execute the program i get only a Jframe. I don't see the circle.Please help.

```
package morsecode;

import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.*;


public class MorseCode extends Frame {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

                MorseCode mc = new MorseCode();
                 MorseCode frame = new MorseCode();


        final String chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
        char word;

                for(int i=1;i<=1;i++)

                {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int x = rand.nextInt(36);
            word = chars.charAt(x);
            System.out.print(word);
                        frame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                        frame.addWindowListener(
      new WindowAdapter()
      {
         @Override
         public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we)
         {
            System.exit(0);
         }
      }
      );

      frame.setSize(400, 400);
      frame.setVisible(true);
                         mc.toMorseCode(word);
                }
    }


    void toMorseCode(char letter)
    {

    switch(letter)
    {
        case 'A' | 'a':
            repaint();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            repaint();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            break;
        case 'B' | 'b':
            repaint();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
             repaint();
              Thread.sleep(1000);
              repaint();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
             repaint();
             Thread.sleep(2000);
            break; ..............
       }
}
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
     Graphics2D ga = (Graphics2D)g;
     ga.setColor(Color.white);
     ga.fillOval(125,125,150,150);

  }
}
```

Comment: Use a logical & consistent code formatting style!  The code indentation is intended to help people follow the program flow.

Answer (score 3):

Two things...

First, calling `Thread.sleep(2000);` within the Event Dispatching Thread will prevent the EDT from processing events on the event queue, including paint events.

Second, `Frame` doesn't have a `paintComponent`.

Adding the `@Override` annotation and trying to call `super.paintComponent` would have highlighted this issue as the code wouldn't have compiled.

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
```

First of all, start by using a `JPanel` to hold your core logic and perform your custom painting.

Second, use a `javax.swing.Timer` to perform animation.  See [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

**Updated**

The basic concept is relatively simple.  You need some kind of second/background thread which can generate the delays between the changes in the output.  You then need to update the UI before each delay based on what type of information you are trying to display.

The implementation becomes tricky because Swing, like most GUI frameworks, is single threaded and not thread safe.

This means, you can not block the GUI thread, doing so will prevent the UI from been repainted, amongst other things and you must update the state of any UI component from within the context of the GUI thread.

This means that while you can use a `Thread` to run in the background, you must ensure that all changes/modifications to the UI are carried out only from within the EDT.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class MorseCodeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MorseCodeTest();
    }

    public MorseCodeTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static final int GAP = 500;
    public static final int DOT = 1000;
    public static final int DASH = 4000;

    public interface Transmitter {

        public void setTap(boolean tap);

    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel implements Transmitter {

        private MorseCode code;
        private boolean tapped;

        public TestPane() {

            code = MorseCode.create('A').addDot().addDash();

            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    Signalar signalar = new Signalar(TestPane.this, code);
                    signalar.execute();
                }

            });

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (tapped) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                int diameter = Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()) / 2;
                int x = (getWidth() - diameter) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - diameter) / 2;
                g2d.fillOval(x, y, diameter, diameter);
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void setTap(boolean tap) {
            tapped = tap;
            repaint();
        }

    }

    public class Signalar extends SwingWorker<Void, Boolean> {

        private final MorseCode code;
        private final Transmitter transmitter;

        public Signalar(Transmitter transmitter, MorseCode code) {
            this.code = code;
            this.transmitter = transmitter;
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<Boolean> chunks) {
            transmitter.setTap(chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1));
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            for (Tone tone : code.getTones()) {
                publish(true);
                Thread.sleep(tone.getDelay());
                publish(false);
                Thread.sleep(GAP);
            }
            return null;
        }

    }

    public static class Tone {

        private final int delay;

        public Tone(int delay) {
            this.delay = delay;
        }

        public int getDelay() {
            return delay;
        }

    }

    public static class DashTone extends Tone {

        public DashTone() {
            super(DASH);
        }

    }

    public static class DotTone extends Tone {

        public DotTone() {
            super(DOT);
        }

    }

    public static class MorseCode {

        private final char value;
        private final List<Tone> tones;

        public static MorseCode create(char value) {
            MorseCode code = new MorseCode(value);
            return code;
        }

        public MorseCode(char value) {
            this.value = value;
            this.tones = new ArrayList<>(25);
        }

        public char getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public MorseCode addDash() {
            return addTone(new DashTone());
        }

        public MorseCode addDot() {
            return addTone(new DotTone());
        }

        public MorseCode addTone(Tone tone) {
            tones.add(tone);
            return this;
        }

        public Iterable<Tone> getTones() {
            return tones;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Swing is a single threaded framework, this means that if you block the  the event dispatching thread (main UI thread), it will be unable to paint or respond to user input.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: I have added sleep thread inside paint method. Still I don't get the expected result.Like for Case A it should blink thrice. for Case B it should blink for twice and so on. Is there any way to achieve it.Please help.

Comment: Swing is a SINGLE threaded environment. Anything that blocks the Swing thread (like `Thread.sleep`) will stop the painting from occurring.

Comment: I removed the Thread.sleep() from switch case and added it in Paint method. I see a single blink.But calling repaint() from case do not work as i expect ( that is repainting in the JFrame).

Comment: You're missing the point. Calling `Thread.sleep` while you're are in the Event Dispatching Thread context will prevent the UI from been painted, full stop! The only solution is to setup a second thread which is responsible for managing the timings and change the state of the UI.  This is problematic as you should never change the state of the UI from any thread OTHER than the EDT, see updates

Comment: OK.. i guess i dont understand still. sorry.. could you please explain me with a sample code.